# Translate wish list, add to cart, Please specify the product required option(s) for

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I can't seem to find the word '**for**' and translate it in the message:
Please specify the product required option(s) **for** "product name".

Does anyone know where it comes from?

Thank you,

Eran

Answer (score 1):

You can add below line into translate.xml or Mage_Wishlist.xml:

```
"%s for ""%s"".","%s FOR "%s"."
```